# My method is executing the IF 'Return' and the Catch 'Return'

Tags: c#, if-statement, return

I feel like I'm losing my mind.  I'm sure there is something simple I'm not seeing.
In the method below, it enters the `Try`, executes the db query and the `If` evaluates true and hits the return statement.  It then moves directly to the `Return` in the `Catch` (skipping over the `_logger`) and exits.

I've stepped through the code and the data coming back from the query is correct.  When I hover over `ex`, it doesn't exist.  I've also tried a `Watch` for `ex`, which says the same thing.

The only other time I was seeing this kind of behavior is when I had  a `Return` directly on the query and if the query returned `NULL`, it would jump directly to the `Return` in the `Catch`.  But its not the case in this instance.

I don't know if it will help, but when I had the `Using` statement inside the `Try` it would execute both the `If` and `Else`.  What the heck am I doing wrong?

```
      public async Task<List<ResourceModel>> GetResourcesByTypeAsync(string resourceTypeName)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceTypeName))
                new ArgumentNullException(nameof(resourceTypeName));

            await using var db = _dbFactory.CreateDbContext();

            try
            {
                var result = await db.ProjectResources
                    .Where(x => x.ResourceType.Name == resourceTypeName)
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .ToListAsync();

                if (result != null)
                {
                    return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    return new List<ResourceModel>();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogCritical(ex.Message);
                return new List<ResourceModel>();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't see the problem, the catch block is only being executed if an exception is thrown within the try block, so if your result != null you just return the result without executing the catch block.

Comment: do you get that log messgae in the catch?

Comment: do you get the correct return value. If you are just confused by stepping through , remeber that async methods completely rewrite the code that you have, the debugger can get confused

Comment: The compiler optimizes jumps, especially in Release mode (be sure to check this). The `ret` instruction may be shared by both exit paths, and the best it can represent that is as the curly brace at the end of the `catch`. The `return` statement probably just pushes the value onto the evaluation stack and then it jumps to the `ret`. Decompile it IL and see what you get.

Comment: What does this code mean: `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceTypeName)) new ArgumentNullException(nameof(resourceTypeName));`? I'm surprised it compiles

Comment: *I don't know if it will help, but when I had the Using statement inside the Try it would execute both the If and Else.* - I think you may be mistaken here. There's no way it's "executing both" unless what you are seeing is two separate instances of the method execution due to it being an `async` call. If you have something looping over `GetResourcesByTypeAsync`, then each time it hits the `await` it is allowing the `GetResourcesByTypeAsync` to be called again. You may have multiple pipes of execution occurring that are leading you to believe it is executing in the wrong order.

Comment: @Flydog57: A `new` expression on its own is fine as a statement, but without the `throw`, it's kind of useless as it doesn't protect against null/empty. Where it would fail to compile is if you were declare a variable and assign it to that expression, since without the braces, the variable declaration is invalid. That certainly was a mistake, though, not throwing the exception instance.

Comment: Also, if you move `return new List<ResourceModel>();`  outside of the try catch, you can remove the else statement as well. That way it will either return `result` if your if condition was true, or return the new `List<ResourceModel>` and would log your exception if there were one.

Comment: Don't throw `ArgumentNullException` when it's an empty string. Throw `ArgumentException` (with an informative message). `ArgumentNullException` is going to send someone on a search for a `null` that isn't being passed. Yes, it's inconvenient to write two tests, but don't lie to the caller.

Comment: I'll try and answer these comments:
@Leppin: It IS executing the Return in the Catch block and instead of the result from the query, I'm getting a null value.

Comment: @pm100: not, its jumping that line.

Comment: @madreflection: sorry, I'm not following?

Comment: @Ibrennan208: as odd as it sounds its not calling the method multiple times.  And I stepped through the code and that's what I observed.  However, I've moved the Using so I only added that as additional info.

Comment: @USMC6072 here's a chat so I can post some code for you: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246323/my-method-is-executing-the-if-return-and-the-catch-return

Comment: Sometimes the debug files seem to get messy like that. I would say: 1: Make sure to build in DEBUG mode. 2. Do a full clean. 3. Restart Visual Studio. 4. Do a full rebuild. 5. Add logs all over the place, or add stuff to a StringBuilder to see what exactly was executed. I've had this happen too a few times, I think for whatever reason, the compiles thinks the dbg files are up to date or something and does not regenerate them, messing up the line numbers.

Comment: In EF Core 6.0 and lower there are a problem (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/async) and you need use AsQueryable in the LINQ query.

Comment: @Gec that makes sense and I am working on that.  So for Clean-Restart-Build didn't help.  Also, if you are interested I recorded a short Loom video stepping through the code.  Maybe there is something I am not describing correctly.  https://www.loom.com/share/ca4252176a804ac9a0abc86ba01d5164

Comment: @Victor this isn't a client-side query but I tried it anyway and no change.  But its good to know about that bug.

Comment: I found I had some crossed wires earlier in my code.  I'm going to work that out and see if it resolves my issues.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: @USMC6072 keep us posted, am curious about the fix.